# c# and Excel Range: how to print to output ranges

Tags: c#, excel

Welll, I hope this won't be a duplicate question, but I'm managing in C# a range of cells in Excel, i have filled an array with a for cycle; to simplify let's say my array is more or less

```
// row,column, i.e. [3,1] is row 3, col 1
Range[] arrayOfRanges;
arrayOfRanges[0] = xlsSheet.Range[ xlsSheet.Range[3,1] , xlsSheet.Range [45,8] ];
arrayOfRanges[1] = xlsSheet.Range[ xlsSheet.Range[46,1] , xlsSheet.Range [89,8] ];
arrayOfRanges[2] = xlsSheet.Range[ xlsSheet.Range[90,1] , xlsSheet.Range [132,8] ];
arrayOfRanges[3] = xlsSheet.Range[ xlsSheet.Range[133,1] , xlsSheet.Range [176,8] ];
arrayOfRanges[4] = xlsSheet.Range[ xlsSheet.Range[177,1] , xlsSheet.Range [207,8] ];
```

Is there a way to use Console.Writeline to have an output similar to this:

```
[ 3 , 1]
[ 46 , 89]
...
```

I Tried with

```
for (int i = 1; i<=arrayOfRanges.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[ " + arrayOfRanges[i][0].Value + "," + arrayOfRanges[i][1].Value + " ]\n");
}
```

But it doesn't seem the correct way.

Comment: "doesn't seem correct"...why, what happens when you run it?

Comment: P.S. in Console.WriteLine (as opposed to Console.Write) you don't have to add `\n` at the end, it's already done for you

Comment: I'm sorry, i edited my question; what it prints is the CONTENT of the cells; i want the number that references the cells. For example, if I have a cell [1,3] ( that is C1) that contains "hello", i don't want to print "hello", but "[1 , 3]"

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Column` and `Row` properties of the Range type:

```
Console.WriteLine($"[{arrayOfRanges[i][0].Row}, {arrayOfRanges[i][0].Column}]");
```

(Also note how I used the $ sign to allow inline parameters inside the string.)

Comment: Thanks! It gave me an error, but with arrayOfRanges[i][1].Row (1 instead of 0) it gives me the first range correctly (in my example [3,1], [46,1], etc)! Now how to obtain the second one ([45,8], [89,8], etc)?